# What is the difference between the pronunciation of 「休校【きゅうこう】」and「急行【きゅうこう】」?

Tags: pronunciation, homophonic-kanji, pitch-accent

「休校【きゅうこう】」と「急行【きゅうこう】」の発音はどう違いますか。

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: "Thank you (in advance)!" は「よろしくお願いします」ですね…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both words have the same reading and pitch accent, so there wouldn't be a difference in pronunciation.